# Get the position of a grid column

Tags: c#, forms, devexpress, controls

How can I position a button within a form so that it is always above a column in a DevExpress grid?

The Grid columns are set up so they cannot be resized, but the grid and columns are re-sized with the form. [System.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) has the [PointToScreen method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) that looks like would it provides this functionality, but not a method in a DevExpress gridviewcolumn.

Comment: Can you use a template for the header and in there put a DIV tag, then get the position of that div tag in JavaScript to get the position on screen?

Answer (score 2):

You can find column coordinates relative to the `GridControl` and translate then to `Form` coordinates. For this you can use `GridColumnsInfo` object that you can get from `GridViewInfo.ColumnsInfo` property. To get `GridViewInfo` object you can use `gridView.GetViewInfo()` method.
Once you find the coordinates, you will need to subscribe to events that occurs at different `GridView` and `GridControl` changes. For example you can subscribe to `GridView.Layout` and
`GridView.LeftCoordChanged` events. For resizing you need to subscribe to `GridControl.Resize` event.
Example:

```
private void UpdatePosition(GridView gridView, string columnName, Control control)
{
    var column = gridView.Columns[columnName];

    if (column == null) return;

    var viewInfo = (GridViewInfo)gridView.GetViewInfo(); //using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.ViewInfo
    var columnInfo = viewInfo.ColumnsInfo[column];

    if (columnInfo != null)
    {
        var bounds = columnInfo.Bounds; //column's rectangle of coordinates relative to GridControl

        var point = PointToClient(gridView.GridControl.PointToScreen(bounds.Location)); //translating to form's coordinates

        control.Left = point.X;
        control.Top = point.Y - control.Height;
        control.Width = bounds.Width;

        control.Show();
    }
    else
        control.Hide();
}
```

You can call this method for every event that you subscribed.

Comment: This works like a Dream. Thanks.  I removed the Setting of the Top as I had laid out my button in a panel just above the grid.  The Button Moves like a dream.